# How do you define in particular a linked list in abstract type theory? Or would you even do that?

Tags: computer-science, type-theory, data-structure

I understand somewhat how abstract `List` is defined.  But still not 100%.  Type theory literature is not that great yet.

I want to know how to build basic data types.  That is the closest stepping stone for me to learning more type theory.

Does type theory go on to define different implementations of list such as a basic pointer-based linked list?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. The impression I have is that implementation and type theory are somewhat orthogonal. I mean this in the sense that type theory specifies more of an interface. If a computer were to implement this interface, it could do so however it pleases under the hood. Honestly if you want to learn how to build basic data types (from a basically type-theoretic perspective) you might want to just learn Haskell. In which case I recommend: http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, there are a lot of arrows pointing toward Haskell right now.  I will learn some basics on repl.it (on web page).  I installed Leksah, but it's so foreign to me that it makes me want to revert back to the command line days.

Comment: Tbh, I never worked out how to use Leksah, I just installed a haskell syntax highlighter for my personal favorite editor (vim).

Comment: Like natural numbers, you would usually just have list types as a basic part of the language with appropriate recursion rules. You can get list types from some other recursive types, but I forget the exact setup you need to make them behave nicely.

Comment: Hint: Simplify your linked lists into [cons lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) and then the type theory may be more straightforward to think through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start from the basic: a list, of type $A$, is a data type $L(A)$ whose values can either be

- the empty list, let denote it by $( )$,
- a pair $(x,xs)$ where $x \colon A$ and $xs$ is a list of type $A$, that is $xs \colon L(A)$.

When implementing this data type in a computer one can think of $xs$ as above as a reference to another list (the tail of your list), so I guess this actually provides the type theoretic version of your pointer-based list.

From a type theoretic perspective the type **list of $A$** can be represented as the least solution to the type equation

$$L=1+A\times L$$

i.e. as the least fixed point to the type operator 
$$X \mapsto 1+A\times X\ .$$

Usually all the classical recursive data types are implementented exactly in this way, i.e. as fixed point for some type-operators.

Other examples of recursive types defined in this way are

- natural numbers, which is the least fixed point for the operator
  $$X \mapsto 1+X$$
- binary trees with nodes of a given type $A$, i.e. fixed the point for the operator $$X \mapsto A+(A \times X \times X)$$
- arbitrary trees, that is the fixed point for 
  $$X \mapsto (A \times L(X))$$
  where $L(X)$ denotes the type of lists of elements of type $X$.

There is also a very simple rule to translate this kind of definitions in haskell code and vice versa but in order to show that a little knowledge of haskell's syntax would be required.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why $xs$?  Why not just $s$?

Comment: I need a reference for fixed points of type operators.  Google is not finding that stuff.  I also looked in HoTT book and no fixed point term found.

Comment: About the first question, the name $xs$ comes from a tradition in programming where working with lists it's common to use $x$ to denote a single element of the list and with $xs$ the remaining (it's a word game based on the fact the in english one usually has to add a final 's' for the plural of a name).  That said one could name it differently, after all those are just variables you can name it as you prefer.

Comment: @EnjoysMathEnj do you mind me asking what's your background? it could be helpful in finding a good reference.